# Exact class name of Crash (Crashlytics)

Tags: flutter, firebase, crashlytics

Integrated crashlytics to my app. I can see crashes. Unfortunately, I couldn't find out the exact name of the class that is causing the crash.
Is there any possibility to find where the crash fired?

[image]

[image]

here is how the crash is being reported:

```
void main(){
FlutterError.onError = (errorDetails) {

  FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterFatalError(errorDetails);

};
PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError = (error, stack) {
FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stack, fatal: true);
return true;
};


Isolate.current.addErrorListener(RawReceivePort((pair) async {
final List<dynamic> errorAndStacktrace = pair;

await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(
  errorAndStacktrace.first,
  errorAndStacktrace.last,
  fatal: true,
);
}).sendPort);
}
```